# Exception showing at the time of launching application - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

> Using below version Android studio version - 3.2 Java client 6.1.0
>   appium 1.9.0
>
> still it showing below exception at the time of app launch

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'my-PC', ip: '172.16.2.99', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:93)
    at com.hp.commercial.framework.common.LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(LocalDriverFactory.java:80)
    at com.hp.commercial.framework.common.TestScriptManager.setUp(TestScriptManager.java:164)
    at com.hp.commercial.sanctuarymobile.testscripts.MyDevices.setup(MyDevices.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code of launch application

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.app1.pkg");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.app1.MainActivity");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

Comment: There are various reason above error pops up. Are you using appium desktop? Appium Desktop doesn't support uiautomator2. You can the full log if it is the problem. The another reason may be your device is not connected properly to the pc or you have not usb debugging permission.

Comment: Where is your webdriver instantiation?  Please add the code for that to your original post (at the very least)  Also, are you sure you have the right package and activity names?  They may be correct, but in general the activity is the same as the package with the activity tacked-on to the end.  Perhaps your package should not include the ".pkg" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1st**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant.MainActivity");
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
//desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

**comment below line and run it will work**

```
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

**solution 2nd**

> > Keep above line as it is, but before that execute 3 commands from command promt

```
adb shell pm list packages -f > D://t.txt
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).